# Merge nested arrays into unique objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I turn a nestedArray into a array of objects based on the values in the nested array?
Here is an example:

```js
const nestedArray = [{
id: "Degree",
options: ["HighSchool", "Undergraduate", "Bachelor", "Master", "Doctor"]
}, {
id: "gender",
options: ["male", "female"]
}]

const arrayOfObjects = []

nestedArray[0].options.map((degree) => {
nestedArray[1].options.map((gender) => {
    let currObject = {}
    currObject[nestedArray[0].id] = degree
    currObject[nestedArray[1].id] = gender
    arrayOfObjects.push(currObject)
})
})

console.log(arrayOfObjects)
```

but the problem with that is sometimes my nestedArray will consist of another nested array called age forexample
How can i make this "univsersal" in a sense?
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2v4L918/15/

Comment: If you were to have another object in the array, would you want to have all combinations of values for that as well. E.g. given another element `{id: "subject", options: ["maths", "german"]}` in the input array would you want all #combinations of degree, gender and subjects?

Comment: @mushroomator Yes, that would than return{
    Degree: "HighSchool",
    gender: "male",
    "subject": "maths"
},
{
    Degree: "HighSchool",
    gender: "male",
    "subject": "german"
},
{
    Degree: "HighSchool",
    gender: "female",
    "subject": "maths"
}

Comment: Careful as `.map` intends to return an array. `.forEach` is a better use here

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're looking for the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Here is an example using one of the answers from this question: [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript).

```js
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript
 */
const cartesian = (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));

const nestedArray = [
  { id: "Degree", options: ["HighSchool", "Undergraduate", "Bachelor", "Master", "Doctor"] },
  { id: "gender", options: ["male", "female"] },
  { id: "subject", options: ["spanish", "geometry"] }
];

const arrayOfEntries = nestedArray.map(({ id, options }) => options.map(option => ({ [id]: option })));

const cartesianProduct = cartesian(...arrayOfEntries);

const arrayOfObjects = cartesianProduct.map(arr => Object.assign({}, ...arr))

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

---

##### Explanation

The snippet above begins by mapping your array of option objects to an array of individual objects using [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015):

```js
[
  { id: "gender", options: ["male", "female"] },
  { id: "subject", options: ["spanish", "geometry"] }
];
// mapped to individual objects: {[id]: option} 
[
  [ { gender: 'male' }, { gender: 'female' } ],
  [ { subject: 'spanish' }, { subject: 'geometry' } ]
]
```

It then takes the cartesian product of these entries:

```js
// cartesian product of individual objects
[
  [ { gender: 'male' }, { subject: 'spanish' } ],
  [ { gender: 'male' }, { subject: 'geometry' } ],
  [ { gender: 'female' }, { subject: 'spanish' } ],
  [ { gender: 'female' }, { subject: 'geometry' } ]
]
```

Finally we `map()` over this array and merge the individual objects by passing them to [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) making sure to assign into an empty object, and using [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to expand the subarray of objects.

```js
Object.assign({}, ...[{ gender: 'male' }, { subject: 'spanish' }])
//            ^^ assign into empty object to avoid reference problems
```